# No module named 'pymysql' in Airflow UI (bashcommand)

Tags: docker, airflow, pymysql, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to run an automated creation of staging table in mysql through a python script that I integrated on my Airflow DAG (docker). The script I'm using is through an external python file that will be run through bashcommand.

When I try to run it on Airflow UI I get this error message.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymysql

start_date=datetime(2021,1,16)

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': start_date,
        'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('etl_2', default_args=default_args)
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='create_stg',
    bash_command='python /opt/airflow/data/staging_dimensions.py',
    dag=dag)
```

Please help! I already installed pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-mysql but not sure if I have to add something on my docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed pymysql several ways:

```js
# try the basics
pip install pymysql
# that didn't work. try this:
pip3 install pymysql
# nope. next:
pip install python3-pymysql
# that doesn't even exist.
```

Nothing worked until I went into PyCharm and explicitly imported pymysql in a python source file. PyCharm flagged it as non-existent, and prompted me to install pymysql. I clicked ok, it did something, and boom it worked. *shrug*